# Header in Elementor is not showing correctly on posts

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I desperately need help. In all other pages the header is fine and correct. But on posts, a white box is around the header and it's not showing properly. I'm Using Xpro plugin to create custom header for desired pages and Elementskit plugin to use Nav Menu as an element.
The odd thing is that for my other site, I had the same problem but it got fixed by itself without me doing anything particular.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNRy0.png)
btw my theme is Astra.

I tried to copy the exact setting the other sites header has for this header but it didn't work.
I used a different pluging (Elementor Header & Footer) but it didn't work.
I tweaked with containers and element's marging and padding and size but it didn't work.
I deactivated the litespeed cache plugin but it didn't work.
I regenerated CSS & Data sync via Elementor>tools>General and it also didn't work.